# testsaslauthd succeeds but sasl-sample-server/client fail

Tags: configuration, sasl

I try to set up `saslauthd` for the XMPP server `prosody` but got stuck somewhere. I used the following documentation:

- http://blogs.mafia-server.net/nur-bahnhof/2013/12/prosody-authentification-ldapactivedirectory/
- http://prosody.im/doc/cyrus_sasl
- https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingProsody

My problem is that I can't get connected. The XMPP client always gets stuck somewhere while exchanging authentication information.

Test using `testsaslauthd` was successful:

```
testsaslauthd -u theuser -p "$pw" 
0: OK "Success."
```

I assume this means that the `/etc/saslauthd.conf` file is correct in this case.

Test using `sasl-sample-server`/`sasl-sample-client` (called in different terminals and copy-pasting the `S:` and `C:` lines):

```
root@xmpp:~# sasl-sample-server -s "xmpp" -m plain
Forcing use of mechanism plain
Sending list of 1 mechanism(s)
S: cGxhaW4=
Waiting for client mechanism...
C: U......................=
got 'PLAIN'
sasl-sample-server: SASL Other: Password verification failed
sasl-sample-server: Starting SASL negotiation: user not found (user not found)
<terminates>

root@xmpp:~# sasl-sample-client -s xmpp -a theuser 
service=xmpp
Waiting for mechanism list from server...
S: cGxhaW4=
recieved 5 byte message
Choosing best mechanism from: plain
returning OK: theuser
Password: 
Using mechanism PLAIN
Preparing initial.
Sending initial response...
C: U......................=
Negotiation complete
Username: theuser
SSF: 0
Waiting for encoded message...
```

I don't understand why `testsaslauthd` succeeds while the other tool combo can't find the user.

After running `/usr/sbin/saslauthd -d` I found the following block in `/var/log/auth.log`. Maybe that's the problem. But whatever I tried, I can't find out what's supplying the invalid parameter:

```
Dec  2 15:42:14 xmpp sasl-sample-server: auxpropfunc error invalid parameter supplied
Dec  2 15:42:14 xmpp sasl-sample-server: _sasl_plugin_load failed on sasl_auxprop_plug_init for plugin: ldapdb
Dec  2 15:42:14 xmpp sasl-sample-server: ldapdb_canonuser_plug_init() failed in sasl_canonuser_add_plugin(): invalid parameter supplied
Dec  2 15:42:14 xmpp sasl-sample-server: _sasl_plugin_load failed on sasl_canonuser_init for plugin: ldapdb
Dec  2 15:42:20 xmpp sasl-sample-client: ldapdb_canonuser_plug_init() failed in sasl_canonuser_add_plugin(): invalid parameter supplied
Dec  2 15:42:20 xmpp sasl-sample-client: _sasl_plugin_load failed on sasl_canonuser_init for plugin: ldapdb
Dec  2 15:42:34 xmpp sasl-sample-server: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
```

Also, I found that `sasl-sample-server` and `sasl-sample-client` use a list of several methods when using without `-m` option but in the file `/usr/lib/sasl2/xmpp.conf` I explicitly select the `PLAIN` method:

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: PLAIN
```

Probably I got the wrong path so I copied the file also to `/etc/sasl/xmpp.conf` and `/etc/sasl2/xmpp.conf` just for case. Unfortunately, I can't find any piece of documentation which tells the paths explicitly for Debian 8.

Also testsaslauthd doesn't seem to care about the service:

```
root@xmpp:~# testsaslauthd -s xmpp -u theuser -p "$pw" 
0: OK "Success."
root@xmpp:~# testsaslauthd -s nonexistingservice -u theuser -p "$pw" 
0: OK "Success."
```

Any idea what else I can to do find the reason?

**Update:**

Obviously, `sasl-sample-server` accesses the file `/etc/sasldb2` which should not happen in ldap mode, I think. Is it possible that this tool doesn't care about configuration and that it doesn't support ldap? Output from strace:

```
stat("/etc/sasldb2", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/sasldb2", O_RDONLY)          = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0a\25\6\0\t\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
close(3)                                = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

First of all: I was on the wrong trace because `sasl-sample-server` doesn't seem to support ldap in any way. It seems it doesn't talk with `saslauthd` but instead has its own implementation. Because of this, it cannot care about the `-a ldap` option of `/usr/sbin/saslauthd`.

So I started through testing with prosody directly. After setting logging to debug I discovered that all the paths for the config file `xmpp.conf` were wrong. But not the path - it's the service name which changed. I found the following hint in http://prosody.im/doc/cyrus_sasl:

> Setting up Prosody to authenticate against LDAP (blog post)
>
> - This post uses xmpp.conf, but the name is now prosody.conf (see cyrus_application_name above)

So the final path was `/usr/lib/sasl2/prosody.conf` (still Debian 8) and its content is still the same:

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: PLAIN
```

With this change I was finally able to log in using xmpp